# Double font-size is not double width on mobile? Desktop ok

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have weird problem with Android Chrome, both mobile and tablet.

**I'm trying to fill container width with text (font-size).**

When I set double font-size for element, I expected that there will be also double width. Works almost great on desktop, but on mobile isn't, width is little bit bigger than 2x.

```
ChildFontSize = "actual child font-size" * "container width" / "child width"
```

**Result:**

On desktop `2 * "font-size" = 2 * "width"` <- OK

On mobile `2 * "font-size" ~= 2.2 * "width"` <- Nope, 2.2 is wrong...

**Exactly:**

1. Check container width, ex. 300px
2. Loop container children, about 6x span
3. Check actual child width, ex. 150px
4. Divide `"container width" / "child width"`, ex. result is 2
5. Check actual child font-size, ex. 30px
6. Multiply `"child font-size" * "result of divide"`, ex. result is 60px

**Live example:**

[Freelance PHP Web Developer Tomas.cc | PHP5, SQL, jQuery, CSS3, HTML5](http://tomas.cc)

**Full code:**

```
var actual;
var newsize;
var multi;
var bigwidth = document.getElementById("big-wrap").offsetWidth;
var bigs = document.getElementsByClassName("big");
for (i = 0; i < bigs.length; i++) {
    actual = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(bigs[i], null).getPropertyValue('font-size')).toFixed(1);
    multi = (bigwidth / bigs[i].offsetWidth);
    newsize = parseFloat(actual * multi).toFixed(1);
    bigs[i].style.fontSize = newsize + "px";
}
```

**Rendered:**

**This is Desktop Chrome, almost perfect.**
[image: Desktop Chrome]

**This is Android Chrome, not good...**
[image]

**Thanks much for help :) Trying to solve it about 3 hours already :/**

Comment: I suspect you are hitting the [Chrome Font Boosting issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84186). There are a few hacks to get around the problem floating around, including this one: [Disable font autosizing in Chrome on Android](http://blog.itcrowd.pl/2014/01/disable-font-autosizing-in-chrome-on.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you need to width to #big-wrap (text container). You want text to be center in horizontal as well as vertical.

what you can do.

```
#big-wrap{
    width:auto;
}
```

remove all width from media queries or make it auto. then

```
#big-wrap span{
    display:block;
}
```

all text in span break down to new line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to express everything in em unit